# Drupal: Disable collapsible fieldset

Tags: drupal

How do I disable collapsible fields in drupal.  By default collapsible is added to fieldsets on the node add form e.g., .

How do I disable this functionality or remove 'collapsible' from the fieldset class?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is a hard reset to do this for every form, you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function and [fieldset](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#fieldset) properties (from Drupal Form API) **collapsible** and **collapsed** to make all fieldset groups not collapsed.

For a better answer see at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-to-expand-the-fieldsets-in-node-add-form. It has any necessary information you need.

Comment: Did you find a solution from our answers? If so please select the correct answer or upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Drupal 7, manage the fields of your content type: /admin/structure/types/manage/[CONTENT TYPE]/fields or navigate: Structure > Content Types > [CONTENT TYPE] > Manage Fields.

In the table you'll see a cog beside the fieldset:

[image]

Select it and change the option to open:

[image]